# Шаблонный конструктор копирования с ограничением

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

Делаю класс матрицы.

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
```

ну, и так далее. Есть конструктор копирования от такой же татрицы:

```
Matrix(const Matrix& M)
:rows(M.rows),cols(M.cols),data(nullptr)
{
```

словом, все работает. Но хочу создавать матрицу из любого подходящего типа, для чего делаю так:

```
template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U,T>>>
Matrix<T>(const Matrix<U>&Q)
:rows(Q.size_r()),cols(Q.size_c())
{
```

При этом код типа

```
Matrix<int> I;
Matrix<double> V = I;
```

не компилируется Visual Studio:

> error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "Matrix<int>" в "Matrix<double>"

Но если я делаю просто

```
template<typename U>
Matrix<T>(const Matrix<U>&Q)
:rows(Q.size_r()),cols(Q.size_c())
{
```

то все нормально работает. Что я делаю не так, что не могу запретить копирование не подходящей матрицы? Как засунуть `enable_if_t` внутрь шаблонной функции шаблонного класса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::enable_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/) принимает значение типа `bool`, а вы ему передаете `std::is_convertible<U,T>`. 
Нужно писать так:

```
template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<U,T>::value>>
Matrix<T>(const Matrix<U>&Q);
```

Comment: Ну я и ступил... :(